# Translate and rotate a cube along a line

Tags: opengl, math, glsl

I have a cube in 3D space and a pre-defined line in 3D as well.
How can I translate and rotate the cube along the given line under the following conditions?
1-We know the starting and ending points of the line.
2-We need to deal with the cube as a solid object. I.e. we can't separate the cube into two rectangles (back and front) to address the problem.

The attached image illustrates the problem.

[please click here to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3i2c.jpg)

Comment: So... you want to move the cube so that the line segment passes through the center of the cube, and is normal to one of the faces, is that right?

Comment: By just defining one line, there are an infinite number of possible transformations since the rotation along this line is not specified. If you have a second direction (a up vector), then the transformation is similar to a lookAt matrix.

Comment: @Beta That's right. It's exactly the requirement.

Comment: Thank you @BDL for your contribution. As Beta mentioned. The line segment passes the center of the cube. We don't care about rotating the cube around this segment. For illustration, consider instead of the cube we have a cylinder.

Comment: What do you know about the initial cube? Just the two points on the line? The modelmatrix of the cube? The coordinates off all six corners?

Comment: @BDL Actually, I know 8 vertices and the cube modelmatrix. By the 8 vertices, I mean the vertices of the two faces of the cube (front and back).  However, the translation must be done in a shader program. So we should find a solution that deals with the cube as one object. I.e we shouldn't separate the cube into front face and back face for example.

Comment: And you want the rotation in the form of an axis and an angle? Or Euler angles, or what?

Comment: @Beta To rotate the cube, I use an axis and an angle. However, if applying Euler angle will simplify the problem I can go this direction. The main problem is that I have to deal with the cube as one object. I.e. The cube should be considered as an object that has 8 vertices. It's quite complicated and it might not be solvable.
Any help is appreciated and thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has two parts: rotation and translation.

The translation part is trivial: translate the center of the cube to the center point of the line.

The rotation part:

1. Construct a unit vector parallel to the line (i.e. normalize the line).

   Pick one of the edges of the cube, normalize it.

   Take the cross product of these two vectors to get the axis of rotation. The magnitude of the product will be the cosine of the angle of rotation. Watch the sign.